# Pandas - reading CSV - difference between dtype='string', dtype=str and dtype='object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dtype

When reading a CSV file into pandas, is there a difference between the three options below when setting the dtype?

Option 1

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype='string')
```

Option 2

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str)
```

Option 3

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype='object')
```

Options 2 and 3 seem notably quicker than option 1 (I'm reading in a CSV with 30,000 rows and 500 columns) which would suggest that there is a difference in how these options work. However I cannot find any documentation that suggests why this is the case - please could someone explain?

Comment: iirc `dtype='string'` uses the experimental `StringDtype` built on top of `ExtensionArrays` (str/object should be equivalent for now) - read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data)

Answer (score 0):

the **dtype** matter of the **Parameters** section within [the documentation of **pandas.read_csv**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) clearly states that

"*Use **str** or **object** together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and **not interpret dtype***".

Such interpretation yields extra burden, e.g. performance loss, especially for the dataframes with great sizes.